# animation-like cloth simulation

Tags: modeling, animation, keyframes, cloth-simulation, proportional-editing

[image][image]
I am trying to recreate this illustration in blender. So far no luck with simulating the bottom part of the paper where it folds while also lending on the character.
I tried cloth simulation, and also proportional editing the creases with keyframes but they seem to dissolve with the cloth simulation. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way.
Added a *Curve Modifier* (using a path curve) that created wave-like distortions, then simulated as Cloth.